# How to create a react build pipeline in vsts with yarn. Couldn't find a package.json

Tags: reactjs, msbuild, azure-devops, yarnpkg

I have a react project, and locally I use just yarn install, yarn build and yarn start to test it at https://localhost:3000

I have the following pipeline:
[image]

However I have this error in the logs:

```
2018-08-10T08:31:34.6206910Z ##[section]Starting: Yarn build
2018-08-10T08:31:34.6211162Z ==============================================================================
2018-08-10T08:31:34.6211307Z Task         : Yarn task
2018-08-10T08:31:34.6211411Z Description  : Executes Yarn
2018-08-10T08:31:34.6211531Z Version      : 2.5.999
2018-08-10T08:31:34.6211633Z Author       : Geek Learning
2018-08-10T08:31:34.6211842Z Help         : [More Information](https://github.com/geeklearningio/gl-vsts-tasks-yarn/wiki/Yarn) (Version 2.5.999).

Dear Angular and Ember CLI users, please check our [known issues](https://github.com/geeklearningio/gl-vsts-tasks-yarn/wiki/Known-Issues)
2018-08-10T08:31:34.6212057Z ==============================================================================
2018-08-10T08:31:35.2261051Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\yarn\1.9.4\x64\yarn-v1.9.4\bin\yarn.cmd build"
2018-08-10T08:31:42.0864621Z yarn run v1.9.4
2018-08-10T08:31:42.1571684Z error Couldn't find a package.json file in "C:\\"
2018-08-10T08:31:42.1572901Z info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
2018-08-10T08:31:42.1822978Z ##[error]Error: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\yarn\1.9.4\x64\yarn-v1.9.4\bin\yarn.cmd failed with return code: 1
2018-08-10T08:31:42.1893252Z ##[section]Finishing: Yarn build
```

But there is actually a package.json

[image]

Comment: What about this issue in your side? Based on the latest messages, it seems that you have resolved the previous issue, for the new issue"Directory xxx is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact", it seems that you don't copy anything to $(Build.artifactstagingdirectory) in your definition, Do you miss a "Copy File" task before the publish artifact? If you get any latest information, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to Archive the results of the build

[image]

Then from the release pipeline, it will take that zip file:

[image]

Not sure if this is the best practice, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you are struggling with it. In your case you should just leave the path empty it defaults to the source repository.

Comment: ok I removed the arguments and the path, and now it works, it looks like it builds something, but I need to publish the build artifacts, but I have no luck with this, where are the build artifacts? https://screencast.com/t/RkkL9DZkzo9

Comment: now you are only restoring artifacts. Most likely you need to run some build script and copy your outputs to $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

Comment: @Luis Valencia, What about this issue now? If you get any latest information, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT please see my own answer below. the yarn task didnt work

Comment: @Luis Valencia, Thanks for sharing your solution here, if possible, you could mark it as the answer. Of course, if I find better workaround, I will share it here. Have a nice day:)

Comment: @LuisValencia when looking at your pipeline in your solution you have two npm steps one to install/restore the packages, one to build your sources. With Yarn you would need the same and according to your disable taks you only had the install.

Comment: It would be great if you could share some working yaml

Comment: It's in the docs @Hoppe 
* https://github.com/geeklearningio/gl-vsts-tasks-yarn/wiki/Yarn-Installer 
* https://github.com/geeklearningio/gl-vsts-tasks-yarn/wiki/Yarn